# Анимация с помощью setInterval на JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Вопрос состоит в том как заставить поезд по второму клику вернуться в начальное положение. Анимация в данном случае рисуется от 0 до 400px в лево. Мне нужно по второму клику чтобы она рисовалась от 400px до 0, тем самым поезд возвращается в начальное положение.
И почему в данной анимации поезд не всегда достигает значения в 400px, и как нам достичь точности при использовании данной функции.

```js
train.onclick = function() {
  var start = Date.now(); // сохранить время начала

  var timer = setInterval(function() {
    // вычислить сколько времени прошло из opts.duration
    var timePassed = Date.now() - start;

    train.style.left = timePassed / 5 + 'px';

    if (timePassed > 2000) clearInterval(timer);

  }, 20);
}
```

```css
#train {
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>
  <img id="train" src="https://js.cx/clipart/train.gif">
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
var isLeftToRight = 0;
var startPosition = 0;
train.onclick = function() {
  isLeftToRight = 1 - isLeftToRight;
  var start = Date.now(); // сохранить время начала

  var timer = setInterval(function() {
    // вычислить сколько времени прошло из opts.duration
    var timePassed = Date.now() - start;
    if (isLeftToRight) train.style.left = timePassed / 5 + 'px';
    else train.style.left = (startPosition - timePassed / 5) + 'px';

    if (timePassed > 2000) {
      clearInterval(timer);
      startPosition = timePassed / 5;
    }
  }, 20);
}
```

```css
#train {
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>
  <img id="train" src="https://js.cx/clipart/train.gif">
</body>

</html>
```